# Why is my Toolbar not collapsing when scrolling?

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar

I am wanting my Toolbar to collapse/hide when scrolling down the recycler view in this fragment however when trying what it says in other posts, it still isn't scrolling. I have tried to add `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` to my toolbar as well as `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to my viewpager but neither seems to work. Here is my code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black">


            <!--- Top Navigation ToolBar  -->

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/menu_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <!--- Bottom Navigation Bar  -->
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabIconTint="@android:color/black"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:tabIndicatorGravity="bottom"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    app:tabRippleColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/black">

                </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

            <!--- Options for View Pager -->

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@id/app_bar"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"></com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_artist_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ArtistHomeFragment"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <!-- Artist Tab Recycler View --> 
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/artist_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

following code works for me in my project...just try adjusting in your code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/customRecycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
    /> </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix my problem unfortunately, I have no idea why my toolbar isn't hiding. Could it be something to do with the fact that you placed your RecyclerView in the same xml/layout as the toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was removing the Relative Layout in activity_main.xml. I am not exactly sure the happenings behind why, but I believe it was somehow causing my toolbar to not close as expected because otherwise it would ruin the Relative Layout potentially? Here is the updated code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <!--- Top Navigation ToolBar  -->

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/menu_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <!--- Bottom Navigation Bar  -->
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIconTint="@android:color/black"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:tabIndicatorGravity="bottom"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabRippleColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/black">

            </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <!--- Options for View Pager -->

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/app_bar">

        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"></com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

After updating com.google.android.material:material from 1.6.0 to 1.9.0 I found the same issue on android 13, when toolbar stops to scroll. I really don't like it when Google breaks the default behavior and makes you investigate and lose hours of work.
The issue solved by moving `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to `AppBarLayout`. Previously this flag was at CoordinatorLayout.